# in Java 8, how can I get int array from Stream<int[]> without using forEach

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

How can I convert  `Stream<int[]>` into `int[]` without using `forEach`?

```
final Stream<int[]> stream = foos.stream()
            .map(foos -> insertQuery(contact, create))
            .map(create::batch)
            .map(Batch::execute); //Batch::execute will return the int[]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`flatMapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#flatMapToInt-java.util.function.Function-)

```
int[] result = stream.flatMapToInt(Arrays::stream).toArray();
```